# In Java how do I initialize elements in array in several lines, not one?

Tags: java, arrays, input, initialization

Hello this is a very simple question but I don't know the answer.
I just want to know how to initialize every element of an array in several lines, because I know how to do it in one line.

My code of initializing them on one line is this way:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();

String[] array = input.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Is your expected final result a 1D array, 2D array, or something else?

Comment: as there are multiple lines, you should first input how many lines. then iterate-> take input-> split->append it to the array. That could be solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My expected result is 1D array.

Comment: @ruhul Okay, so there is no possible way, without making an input of how many lines they should be.

Comment: Although its not part of the problem, but i think using Arraylist would be better in this situation. It will allocate memory dynamically as you don't know how many lines there could be

Comment: @shb Yes of course and indeed, but in my task is required array, not list.

Comment: @shb How can you do it with Arraylist tho?

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров was too long to put it here. check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using an ArrayList

```
String s = "Too Many\nLines Here\nNo its only three"; 
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s); 
List<String> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+")));
//to add next line
array.addAll(Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+")));
//.. and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Array must have fixed size, and you cannot change it once declared. About your problem, you can create an Array which has the size is greater than your expectation. Because you don't know how many it will loop, you can make the while loop and a marker to stop inputing ("quit" or "stop" or something else special user can't input...). Eg:

```
String[] arr = new String[1000];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int counter = 0;

while (true) {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    if ("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        break;
    }
    arr[counter++] = input;
}
```